# how to keep position one div fixed relative to other moving ones?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I want to keep the #typebox fixed in its position even when chatboxes move on scrolling up and down.

I have tried keeping the position:relative for #innerbox (which is container of #typebox) and position:absolute for #typebox but this did not meet the requirement.

I also tried keeping position:fixed for #typebox but this vanishes the #typebox and the scrollbar as well.

I tried referring to other similar question but could not find what am I doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated :)

```css
#outerbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid DodgerBlue;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
#innerbox {
  width: 240px;
  height: 440px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid DodgerBlue;
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: url("allo.gif");
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#chatbox1 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  margin-top: 100%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox3 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox4 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#typebox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px grey;
  margin-top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4">
        <h1>Vaas</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4" id="outerbox">
        <div id="innerbox">

          <div id="chatbox1"></div>

          <div id="chatbox2"></div>

          <div id="chatbox3"></div>

          <div id="chatbox4"></div>
          <div id="typebox">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color:#00BFFF; padding-right:3px;" aria-hidden="true"> Say something...</i>
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o" style="color:#808080;padding-left:30px; padding-right:5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-microphone" style="color:#808080;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Apply `position: relative` to `outerbox` instead of `innerbox` and keep `absolute` positioning of the `typebox` (I have given `bottom: 50px` for illustration)

```css
#outerbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid DodgerBlue;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  position: relative;
}
#innerbox {
  width: 240px;
  height: 440px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid DodgerBlue;
  margin: 20px;
  background-image: url("allo.gif");
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#chatbox1 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #0097A7;
  margin-top: 100%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox2 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox3 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#chatbox4 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #009688;
  background-color: #00BCD4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#typebox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 8%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px grey;
  margin-top: 50%;
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4">
        <h1>Vaas</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4" id="outerbox">
        <div id="innerbox">

          <div id="chatbox1"></div>

          <div id="chatbox2"></div>

          <div id="chatbox3"></div>

          <div id="chatbox4"></div>
          <div id="typebox">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color:#00BFFF; padding-right:3px;" aria-hidden="true"> Say something...</i>
            <i class="fa fa-smile-o" style="color:#808080;padding-left:30px; padding-right:5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-microphone" style="color:#808080;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" "col-xs-4"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @shuchi let me know your thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Thank u sir this helped me.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong-  innerbox is the immediate parent of typebox then why does position:relative not work for innerbox?

Comment: That is because `innerbox` contents scroll and you can put it to `bottom` but `typebox` scrolls along with the other contents...

Comment: @shuchi good to know the problem is fixed :) also don't forget to upvote and accept answer too, thanks!